# Start Process with Parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, process

Im trying to code a client for samp(Gta San Andreas Multiplayer) which one will be set username and connect server automatically.

Samp have own parameters for set username, server ip, server port etc.

My problem is my process just take the first parameter. I need use 2 parameters.

I searched at google about this, find something but they mostly was using cmd and parameter type doesn't match with mine. I tried several way to solve my problem but i failed.

There's my code;

```
                islem.StartInfo.FileName = yol + "\\" + "samp.exe";
                string parametre = " -c -h192.168.1.2 -n"+textBox1.Text+"";

                islem.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(parametre);
                islem.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(yol + "\\" + "samp.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = "-c -h192.168.1.2 -n" + textBox1.Text;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Should also use `Path.Combine()` rather than the hard-coded `"\\"` delimiter.

Comment: still same getting the just IP adress